# Windows forms editor keeps recreating an event method

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have a C# application with a custom control. The custom control class looks like this:

```
public partial class DetNumericUpDown : UpDownBase
{
    public event EventHandler ValueChanged;

    /* some public methods */

    public DetNumericUpDown() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Then I have several instances of DetNumericUpDown in a form file Main.cs, placed from the designer. Each of these instances have their own ValueChanged event defined, but instead of placing them in Main.cs I have moved them for clarity to another file OtherFile.cs. The problem is that each time I try to use the windows forms designer on Main.cs it recreates these methods in Main.cs and then complains the methods are defined twice. That only happens with the DetNumericUpDown instances, as I have moved some event methods from other controls into OtherFile.cs and it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The event handlers have to be defined in the same class as the form hosting the control. Why do you need to move them around?

Comment: For clarity, there is no other reason. Have they? Moving them to other file totally works fine with any other control... EDIT: They are in other file but within the same class.

Comment: Are you drag dropping the custom controls onto the Form, or are you doing it in the Designer Code? And show "what methods" are recreated and how you are wiring up the ValueChanged event?

Comment: The custom control is being dropped into the Form from the windows forms designer. The method created is an empty instance of nudControl_ValueChanged with the correct signature. The code for wiring up the event is automatically generated by the designer and looks like this:

this.nudControl.ValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.nudControl_ValueChanged);

Comment: The designer just doesn't know that you moved the existing event handler.  Nor can it know, it knows beans about OtherFile.cs.  So as soon as you make *any* change to the form, it sees that there is something wrong (ValueChanged gets assigned but no matching method found) and fixes the problem.  You *can* let the designer know about OtherFile.cs, it requires editing the project file by hand with, say, Notepad.  Locate OtherFile.cs and add `<DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>`, same way that Form1.Designer.cs works.