# Separating hundreds of event handlers

Tags: c#

This is an issue of code management that I've run into several times. Say I've got a winforms application, and there is a lot of content - hundreds of controls worth of content, most of which have an attached event handler and method. When looking for recommendations on how to separate out such a large file, the 2 big ones that come to mind are regions & partial classes. However, these are both damned by almost every top answer out there.

So I'm wondering, what is the best practice for separating out something like this? It wouldn't make sense to separate them into new classes as they're simply control event handlers. Regions are nice but can still be extremely messy with so much code. I'm kind of at a loss, I can't figure out how to apply the SRP here and any recommendation I see seems to be considered bad practice.

Comment: What's wrong with partial classes? I've used them before to keep code separate and in my case it works nicely. Seems like a "ClassName_EventHandlers.cs" file would be a great way to keep your code separate and easy to find all in one spot.

Comment: Moving event handlers into another partial class [requires project surgery](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37762519/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant: In visual studio 2015, the Designer "Go To Definition" right click option mostly finds event handlers in partial classes without updating the project file, unlike the 2012 & before "Navigate To Handler".

Answer (score 4):

The 'proper' way would be to split the form up into user controls.

Partial classes are meant to separate generated code from user code and regions are just layout (and useless in my opinion, but that is just an opinion)

Splitting the window in user controls promotes proper encapsulation and re-use.

Depending on the project, it might be too expensive to clean it up but splitting out couple of easy ones might help the readability and might save you some time when debugging. Also, when adding new controls and logic, consider adding user controls and start the process of splitting up that way. The cost will then be spread over a longer period and will only be paid for part that you actually use and need to be readable.

Comment: This is the way to go.  If the response is that the form doesn't split up naturally into controls, then there is something wrong headed about the design, since you should be able to reuse the same handlers troughout.

Comment: This is a glib answer that ignores the real-world cost/benefit considerations. It's unlikely that any of the controls would be genuinely reusable without even more work, so this advocates major surgery with the only benefit being "proper encapsulation". It also ignores the extra complexity as the form would require the individual controls to interact with each other in a new way from before.

Comment: I've looked into user controls but have run into some further questions. What is the best way to have a user control interact with another user control? e.g. if usercontrol2 needs to update a value in usercontrol1, what is the best way to get a reference of usercontrol1 to usercontrol2? Would it be to simply pass a reference to the main form through when you create usercontrol2, and then access a public variable that contains usercontrol1?

Comment: Well, since we don't see the code (thank goodness) we can only make assumptions. But with so many controls one can at least hope that there are actually groups that work together somewhat independently; thos groups would indeed make good UCs, re-use or not.

Comment: Another pattern I often use are controller classes that encapsulate certain functions and can be reused right away. Instead of coding all the handlers for all the clients of the controller only one set is coded and in the controller class. But of course this all speculation..

Comment: @Branden: Yes, that can be done and all public controls can be referenced via qualification: `uc1.someCheckBox.Checked` but the main goal really should be to minimze this kind of dependencies and  put the unavoidable stuff into accessors, usually properties. - And yes, this will be a major operation, as has to be expected. Make sure you get clearance first ;-)

Comment: Please do not get into a discussion. That is not what Stack Overflow is for. If you have another answer post it, if you have another question, post it. This question is close to being "primarily opinion-based" but still valuable IMO.